# add/assign value to row which are null with previous row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to add/assign value to row which are null with previous row value in SQL Server 2005

Example:

```
Col1  Col2 
1      45
NULL   30
2      20
3      40
NULL   30
NULL   20
4      40
```

Output must be like this

```
Col1  Col2 
1      45
1      30
2      20
3      40
3      30
3      20
4      40
```

Comment: Is there any other information in the table to decide the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume that you have a column named `id` which is a primary key, or your default order is made by this field, and I assume that your table's name is t1.

here is the query which gives the result you need:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT a.id, nested.col1, a.col2 FROM t1 as a 
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM t1 as b WHERE a.id > b.id and b.col1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY b.id DESC) nested
WHERE a.col1 IS NULL
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is another column(s) in the table to decide the order, it can't be done

There is **no** guaranteed order in SQL without an ORDER BY. So we don't know which NULL goes where or in which order the data will be read from the database.

An ORDER BY is required to guarantee any order and the data will come with NULLs first then populated rows. If a SELECT without ORDER BY does return rows in your expected order above, then it is *coincidence* only

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @table as table(Col1 int,Col2 int)

insert into @table values(1,45)
insert into @table values(NULL,30)
insert into @table values(2,20)
insert into @table values(3,40)
insert into @table values(NULL,30)
insert into @table values(NULL,20)
insert into @table values(4,40)

select * from @table

while exists(select 1 from @table where Col1 is null)
begin
update t1 set t1.Col1=t2.Col1 from
     (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 0)) as RowNo,Col1 
            from @table)as t1 cross apply 
     (select top 1 * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 0)) as RowNo,Col1
            from @table)as t 
     where t.RowNo<t1.RowNo order by RowNo desc)t2 where t1.Col1 is null
end

select * from @table
```

This query works for you, if you not concerned to the performance!

Comment: Thanks, query is working fine, I need to consider performance also here.

Comment: You can also; `over (order by (select 0))` which would apply the same "ordering" as a select without an order by

Comment: @Alex K Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer. It gives better performance than the `over (order by rand())`